# Can you suggest a good reference book on Sound Design and mixing for Film?

Tags: mixing, books, references

The title says it all.   What is a good hard-copy resource out there that can offer a foundation for A for V mixing technique?  Perhaps one that walks the reader through the process - Raw tracks to printed master.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There's not really just one way to do this, there are practically as many ways as there are practitioners, possibly more as many of us tends to adopt to the project rather than always doing it the same way. As such, and due to the fact that it's a humongous field to cover, I don't think there are actual walk-throughs for this.

What do exist though, is several good books in the more general and practical field. Of your question to judge I take it you don't have much experience in this, and even if you're a full-blown pro, this is still a very good and easily read book - The Sound Effects Bible by Ric Viers.

Comment: I completely agree. "Sound Design" by David Sonnenschein is also a good and readable book. It takes you trough the process and shows you the basics of Sound Design for film..
I think you can learn more by reading this social sound design blog though :)

Comment: Have it.  Love it.   Thanks for the suggestion! 

Comment: @Audiophile :-)

@Taco Totally hear you there! I love that book, but I didn't mention it at first as it's more into the psychology of sound, which some people seems to have some problem with, though that's something I really really love with it :-)

Comment: + "Sound design"

Answer (score 2):

John Purcell's Dialogue Editing book covers this process in broad strokes from dailies -> printmasters.  Very broad strokes, because all the ins and outs of dialogue/ADR editing alone would fill an Encyclopedia Brittancia set easily.  But, it does offer a very well rounded and approachable introduction to dialogue editing, and where it sits within the entire process of post sound (and, what that post sound process is).  It doesn't have extensive details, but its a good book to start with.  One VERY nice bit is it speaks to some of the etiquette to be aware of.  Some of it has been great suggestions in my opinion, and I've adapted some of his ideas on this topic into how I work with my clients and colleagues.

Also, Dave Yewdall's Practical Art of Motion Picture Sound covers this same process too but more from the FX angle.  It's a bit older of a book, and full of poignantly dry humor, but still very good and very relevant to today's post sound world.  There's no doubt about it, this man has been in the trenches for a very long time and in a variety of ways, so there's a wealth of knowledge to be grasped from this book.

The absolute best resource though is being a part of the process itself, or sitting in on it - ranging from the cutting room up to the dub stage.  My experiences have been that books and classroom material only go so far.  The hands-on experience is where it counts, whether you're in the trenches or observing intently from the sidelines.

Comment: Tabbing over to Amazon right now....I think the former suggestion is just what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've answered similar question here: [i want learn about sound mixing when shooting film, can anyone suggest me a good DVD or book to get start?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12263/i-want-learn-about-sound-mixing-when-shooting-film-can-anyone-suggest-me-a-good)

Get Bob Katz - Mastering Audio, incredibly in-depth and everything you'll ever need to know (probably).