# i want learn about sound mixing when shooting film, can anyone suggest me a good DVD or book to get start?

Tags: mixing, books, sound-design, recording

i want learn mixing for film. i know the boom pool connect to audio mixer and it connect to a recording device when you shooting. i don't know even basic thing about how to separate 2 different audio coming from different mic or mix that together in shooting, its just basic but i don't even know that. can u guys please recommend me any good book or DVD to get start??

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to know about location sound isn't how to push buttons and faders, or really even how to use recorders. The single most important thing to know is how to use a microphone. If you don't know what various mics should sound like, in various conditions, it doesn't matter how you record it or what track it's on or what the level is, it will be bad.

The best thing I could recommend is to get paid to learn. Go and be a boom op first. Learn to know what you are hearing and how to use various mics in various conditions, optimum or horrible. Simply reading will not train your ears or you ability to make decisions and choices on the fly. Learn what it takes to be a good boom op. How to solve the puzzle that is each shot and how to dance with the talent and crew when Action is called.

On set recording is dealing with pressure and troubleshooting. How can you get that mic where it needs to be and around all the lights, stands, the dolly, the focus puller, the gripology, dealing with a horrible location, in advance. You will want the Locations people and the cinematographer to be your best friends. A book won't tell you how to charm a cinematographer who wants to light your boom op off the set.

Answer (score 1):

Tomlison Holman - Sound for Film and Television, is good book too. Includes stuff from shooting to post.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got the Roll Sound book which covers a lot of useful stuff. http://www.rollsoundbook.com/ sale on at the moment too.

You could try YouTube for some basic info. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Rose - Producing Great Sound for Film & Radio is not bad.

Bob Katz - Mastering Audio is a kind of audio engineer's bible. (for post sound)

Ric Viers - The Sound Effects Bible - good for an introduction to most audio concepts that are required knowledge to capturing good sound.

Some websites

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/indepth/tips_and_solutions/Audio

http://filmsound.org/

Depends what angle your coming at it from? (director wanting to learn more? musician wanting to learn sound design?)

Best of luck.
Nicol

Comment: I agree with Nicol's list, but also would suggest signing up on Jeff Wexler's forum at jwsound.net. Just listen and read for a while before asking any questions. That board is almost wholly focused on production recording for film and television, which will be a lot more specific to what you need to learn than Social Sound Design. (No offense meant to this great community or its members.)

Comment: +1 for Ric Viers - The Sound Effects Bible Very helpful for beginners

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for material on post or location... but I'm currently reading "S. Dean Miles - Location Audio Simplified", and can already say that only halfway through the book, I've learned tonnes!

I highly recommend it (you can see some sample pages on Trew Audio's website):
http://www.trewaudio.ca/store/product.php?productid=768
http://www.locationaudiosimplified.com/BookStore2010.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait for a while Ric Viers' nearly done with his new book which is unofficially titled "[The Location Sound Bible](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1615931201/ref=rdr_ext_tmb)" which is supposed to cover sound mixing and stuff.

[Update] Release date is now the 1st of September, looking forward to it.