# books on mixing films?

Tags: mixing, film

does anybody know of any book that deals with Mixing of films.. i have downloaded two books

1. The Mixing Engineers Handbook.
2. Mix Smart Pro Audio Tips For Your Multitrack Mix
   from the internet but these books basically focus on music mix.

these two books are pretty helpful but i would also like to read more on how to go about mixes in film..how to handle dialouges, ambiences, background music etc.

Comment: Downloaded, eh?

Comment: @Internet I checked and both this books are offered in Amazon Kindle editions (and likely other online book stores), so I believe it's worth giving this individual the benefit of the doubt before we jump to any conclusions.

Comment: As a friendly piece of advice, I do not recommend sharing such information on SSD and/or supporting such information dissemination.  While I cannot speak for the community, my understanding of fellow peers and industry wide is that there is a strong pro-IP-protection sentiment, as our line of work is IP content creation, whether it be the final content appearing in  media or the teaching literature (books) written by those sharing their craft.  Personally I find this need to ride off the backs of our industry peers for 'free' quite disrespectful to them and our craft at large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my choice:

1. http://www.amazon.com/Dialogue-Editing-Motion-Pictures-Invisible/dp/0240809181/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1361733846&sr=8-1&keywords=dialogue+editing+for+motion+pictures
2. http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Art-Motion-Picture-Sound/dp/0240812409/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1361733899&sr=1-1&keywords=practical+art+of+motion+picture+sound

i cant guarantee that this books are about mixing films, but they seems to me pretty helpful.

Comment: These are two good books.  #1 definitely provides a 'brief' but well-rounded overview to the dialogue world.  #2 is a great resource overall for the post sound process and all of it's facets (more from an FX angle), although he's got some pretty dry humor but it's a good read.

Answer (score 1):

Start [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12251/can-you-suggest-a-good-reference-book-on-sound-design-and-mixing-for-film) and [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12263/i-want-learn-about-sound-mixing-when-shooting-film-can-anyone-suggest-me-a-good). Plus check out the Related box below the SSD SoundCloud player on the right hand side of any page on SSD.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a lot of the decisions in how to setup the session in a mix and what to do with the elements depend on your taste and the type of film you are working on. Story elements can determine how your setup deviates from those in other films. The books I would recommend are David Sonnenscheins "Sound Design" and Barbara Flückingers "Sound Design" if you read german. Not exactly on mixing, but I think also in mixing story and concept are very important.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth checking this one out:

Audio Postproduction for Film and Video, by Jay Rose

Answer (score 0):

eyehear05 - I cannot believe you are actually posting piratebay links in this thread and feel fine about it! You are asking about books and then tell us that you don't actually read real books!

D. Yewdall's Practical art of Motion Picture sound is probably the best book that touches upon the subject of feature film mixing. However you can learn much more here on Social Sound Design, Gearslutz and DUC. But the best advice I can give you is this: listen to and analyse the movies that you think sound good. Try to figure out what is going on and try to apply the same to your own projects. Then find a good mixer in your area and get a chance to sit in with him/her. You will learn more in a day than you have learnt in your life.

Stop reading those piratebay books - they are useless. :)

Comment: it seems that posting the torrent links of the books i mentioned  have hurt some people's feelings, so i deleted them! my idea was not to disrespect anyone or anyboody's work. i sincerely apologise.